# Why is the logical operator '&' ignored in terra R when comparing two SpatRast?

Tags: r, raster, logical-operators, terra

When using the logical '&' on two overlaying SpatRast, the comparision function below seems to be ignored in terra, but gives the expected vector as an output in a raster. Why is that?

```
r1 <- terra::rast(ncols=5, nrows=5, xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=5)
r2 <- raster::raster(ncols=5, nrows=5, xmn=0, xmx=5, ymn=0, ymx=5)
r1[] <- 1:25
r2[] <- 1:25
s1 <- r1
s2 <- r2
r1[s1>9 & r1>9]
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
r2[s2>9 & r2>9]
#[1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your example. I get the expected result for the `terra` `SpatRaster`, `r1[s1 > 9 & r1 >9]`. Perhaps you should restart your R session?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem was my terra version (1.5.21). I now updated to 1.6.17 and it works

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to assume that the `&` gets ignored. At least you do not show any evidence. Did you have a look at `(s1>9 & r1>9)`?

Also, what version of "terra" are you using? I am asking, because it seems that the CRAN version returns what you expect.

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6.17
r1 <- terra::rast(ncols=5, nrows=5, xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=5)
r1[] <- 1:25
s1 <- r1
r1[s1>9 & r1>9]
# [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Comment: I've been using terra 1.5.21. Now it works (see reply to John Polo). Love the terra package by the way. Keep up the good work!